# Find a the density function for Y(1) = min(Y1, Y2, . . . , Yn).

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose that the length of time Y it takes a worker to complete a certain task has the probability density function given by
$f(y)=\begin{cases} e^{-(y-\theta)} &, y>\theta\\ 0 & ,elsewhere \end{cases}$
where θ is a positive constant that represents the minimum time until task completion. Let
$Y_1, Y_2, . . . , Y_n$ denote a random sample of completion times from this distribution. Find

a the density function for Y(1) = min(Y1, Y2, . . . , Yn).
b E(Y(1)).

Could anyone get me started on this since the random sample is not independent?

Comment: Let $j = \min_i(Y_i)$.  What's the likelihood that the (independent of $Y_j$) samples are all greater than $Y_j$?  (This is the intersection of the conditions that each of the $n-1$ samples is $ \geq Y_j$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- The sample times are presumably independent.
- Find the probability $Y_i \le x$ for a particular $i$
- Find the probability $Y_i \gt x$ for a particular $i$
- Find the probability $Y_i \gt x$ for all $i$
- Find the probability $\min_i(Y_i) \gt x$
- Find the probability $\min_i(Y_i) \le x$
- Find the density function for $\min_i(Y_i)$
- Find the expectation of $\min_i(Y_i)$

Comment: could you show me how to find the probability for $ Y_i \le x$ for a particular i ?

Comment: $\displaystyle P(Y_i \le x) = \int_{y=\theta}^x e^{-(y-\theta)} dy = 1-e^{-(y-\theta)}$ for $x \gt \theta$

Comment: just want to put the right position for all your hints, is it going to be let $U = min (Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n)$. $P[U \le t] = 1 - P[U > t] = 1 - P[Y_1 > t, Y_2 > t ,..., Y_n > t] = 1 - [1-F_Y (t)]^n $ Then we take the derivatives of $P[U \le t] = 1 - [1-F_Y (t)]^n$ to find the density function for $min_i (Y_i)$?

Comment: Yes, but $1 - [1-F_Y (t)]^n$ is not difficult to express in terms of $e,y,\theta,n$.  Try it.

Comment: $P[U > t] = 1 - [-e^{-(y-\theta)}]^n$ Is this right?

Comment: density for $Y_{(1)}$ is $n[-e^{-(y-\theta)}]^{n-1} e^{-(y-\theta)}, y > 0$    for $E(Y_{(1)}) = 1-ye^{-(y-\theta)}-e^{-(y-\theta)} + y $, right?

Comment: You have a sign error or two at the start and can simplify: $P[Y_{(1)} \gt y] = e^{-n(y-\theta)}$, while the density  for  $Y_{(1)}$ is $ne^{-n(y-\theta)}$.  Your statement for the expectation is very wrong as it should not include $y$

Comment: The way I calculate density for $Y_{(1)}$ is $f_U (t) = n [F_y(t)]^{n-1} f_y(t) = n [1-e^{-(y-\theta)}]^{n-1} e^{-(y-\theta)}$, for $y > \theta$...does it look right to you...if you could you show me how to get to your density answer?

Comment: You should have $$P[Y_i \le y] = 1-e^{-(y-\theta)},$$ $$P[Y_i \gt y] = e^{-(y-\theta)},$$ $$P[Y_{(1)} \gt y] = [e^{-(y-\theta)}]^n = e^{-n(y-\theta)},$$ $$F_{Y_{(1)}}(y)= P[Y_{(1)} \le y] = 1 - e^{-n(y-\theta)},$$ $$f_{Y_{(1)}}(y)=  ne^{-n(y-\theta)}$$

Comment: Got it...before getting to the detail of my calculation for $E(Y_{(1)})$ ... I just want to check with my setup matches with yours first....$$
\int_\theta^y xe^{-(x-\theta)} dx
$$? If this is different from yours, could you show yours?

Comment: Two points: (1) you have the original density there when you should have the density for the minimum; and (2) $y$ is not the correct top limit of the integration

Comment: For (1), after looking at your comment, I am a bit confused as to how to write out the density for the minimum. Could you show it?..For (2), what is the top limit is going to be .... since my thinking is for the support $ y > \theta $...so it should integrate up to t.

Comment: The density is $ne^{-n(y-\theta)}$ and the integral should go to infinity

Comment: if I integral this, my answer is infinity through...if not, could you show me your answer?

Comment: No.  $\displaystyle \int_\theta^\infty ne^{-n(x-\theta)} dx = 1$ and $\displaystyle \int_\theta^\infty xne^{-n(x-\theta)} dx$ is also finite.

Comment: so your answer for $E(Y_{(1)})$ is what?

Comment: The shifted expectation of an [exponential random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with rate $n$

Comment: this info does not relate to this problem though...

Comment: I did not see why $\int_\theta^\infty ne^{-(x-\theta)} dx $is 1. Could you explain that?

Comment: You are missing an $n$ in the exponent as in $\displaystyle \int_\theta^\infty ne^{-n(x-\theta)} dx = \left. -e^{-n(x-\theta)} \right|_\theta^\infty = 0 -(-1)= 1$.

Comment: you have to multiply by x inside this integral right?

Comment: For the expectation, yes: $\displaystyle \int_\theta^\infty xne^{-n(x-\theta)} dx$.  Integration by parts will do it

Comment: However, when I integrate this, I got $x - \frac{1}{n}$...which does not make much sense to me... if that is different from yours, could you show me how did you get your answers?

Comment: You should have $\left. -\left(x+\frac1n\right) e^{-n(x-\theta)} \right|_\theta^\infty $ and your result should have $n$ and $\theta$ but not $x$

Comment: The answer is $\theta - \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Close: $\theta + \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: you are right as I mess up with one of the sign...finally...